# Altium connection to multiple devices with same pad-to-pad trace len for each path

Tags: altium

I am currently tring to route a SoC to two DDR3 chips.

Length matching is required for the signals SoC->DDRA and SoC->DDRB. Altium is able to measure a nets length by building the sum of all trace-object's lengths that are part of a net. But this doesnt help me, as the signal lanes will split up and partly be routed to just DDRA or just DDRB.

Does Altium allow to measure the length of a trace between two pads?

If not, I'll add net ties and split up all the signals but I'd hate this approach, as the schematic gets really messy + I got netTie components all over the PCB.

Altium Version is Winter 09.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally stumbled upon the functionality I was looking for.

It is called xSignals!
http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/High+Speed+Design+with+xSignals

Seems like these options do not exist in Altium 09.
From the Altium Website:
"With the introduction of support for xSignals in Altium Designer 15.0, xSignals can be created using the Design » xSignals » Create xSignals command"